# Is there a way to uninitialize variables in a class c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

So recently I've just come across a video about c++ explaining the use of member initializer lists. I was wondering if there is a way to use a member uninizializer (or something of that sort) list of sort in the deconstructor. For example I have a class called Entity that has 2 private values x and y and I am setting them both to 5 in my Initializer via a member initializer list but I have to uninitialize them in the deconstructor the normal way(x = 0;...).

```
class Entity
{
private:
    int x, y;
public:
    Entity(): x(5), y(5)
    {
    }

    ~Entity() //Here I want to set x and y to 0 like this: x(0), y(0)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: What's the purpose of setting them to zero just before they cease to exist?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Whenever you would want to "uninitialize" a trivial object, you can just ignore it's current value. It's not a testable property anyway. Just pretend it's uninitialized if you want.

Comment: Use RAII. In other words, wrap your ints into a class with destructor that sets the value to zero. You don't then need to write a destructor for the class which uses these wrapped ints. But, indeed, why?

Comment: @hyde 99.999% of the time that will be optimized away as it has no effect.

Comment: @NathanOliver Same applies to the code in question, though. Also, that optimization can (and must, if this zeroing would indeed be required to happen) be avoided by using `volatile`.

Comment: @hyde That is what I was saying.  This and your idea will both optimize away as it does nothing to affect the observable behavior of the program.  Only if the variable is declared as `volatile` will it actually matter (casting to volatile can be optimized away if the compiler knows the source is not volatile.)

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean `int x; volatile int * volatile xp=&x; *xp=0;` can be optimized away? I kinda doubt that, that'd be crazy IMO... Are you sure?

Comment: This is just some dummy code that I wrote to see if there is a way to deconstruct an object with a member list. I don't know where you would use it but I'm just curious because I couldn't find anything after googleing.

Comment: This feature makes no sense whatsoever, so nobody has though of adding it to the language.

Comment: @hyde It depends on the circumstance.  Lets say in in the OP's code they did `const_cast<volatile int&>(x) = 0;` in the destructor the compiler can optimize that away since `x` was not volatile to start with and changing the value in the destructor is not needed.

Comment: @n.m. yeah ok I am just learning c++ and I thought there could be a use behind it.

Comment: @KingNex In that case solution is to write RAII class, which does the uninitialization in its own destructor, much like for example `std::unique_ptr` does for pointers.

Comment: Yeah I think I'm going to do some research on RAII classes and thank you for answering.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right. But using "double volatile" pointer variable should prevent any optimizations from removing the assignment or the whole pointer (and also force the int to be in memory, because its address is needed).

Comment: @hyde It has a good chance to work, and at least the big 3 will not optimize it away.  That said, a good enough optimizer should be able to optimize it away.

Comment: @NathanOliver But `volatile` means there cam be external observers. A debugger is an example of a possible external observer. I don't think optimizing that away is ever allowed. Storing an address to pointer, reading the address value back and storing 0 to that address all must happen. That's what volatile means.

Comment: @KingNex that's the work of deconstructor, and please don't call it a deconstructor (it's destructor ;) :D)

Answer (score 2):

After the destructor finishes, the object is destroyed, and you will no longer be able to access the `x` and `y` members.  Therefore, assigning zero to them is not useful, and the compiler will probably optimize it out because observable behavior is not changed.

If your intent is to zero the memory for cryptographic reasons, an assignment or even a simple `fill` or `memset` probably won't be enough — it can be optimized out.  See, for example, [cppreference `memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset#Notes).  You may have to use something more complicated, for example:

```
~object()
{
    std::fill(const_cast<volatile T*>(data.begin()),
              const_cast<volatile T*>(data.end()),
              0);
}
```

If your intent is to write an RAII class that releases the resources upon destruction, you probably won't want to simply reset the value of the resource handler.  For example:

```
template <typename T>
class object {
    T* elem;
public:
    // ...
    template <typename... Args>
    object(std::in_place_t, Args&&... args) // for example
    {
        elem = new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    ~object()
    {
        delete elem; // elem = nullptr won't work
    }
};
```